# Столкновения java,не получается реализовать

Tags: java

Есть один код(копи-паста)

```
package things;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//класс-квадрат
final class Square {
    public int x, y, w, h;

    Square() {
    }

    Square(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
    }

    //пересечение квадратов
    public static boolean isIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        return ((a.x < (b.x + b.w)) &&
                (b.x < (a.x + a.w)) &&
                (a.y < (b.y + b.h)) &&
                (b.y < (a.y + a.h)));
    }

    //пересечение квадратов с выталкиванием
    public static boolean isLockIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        if (!isIntersect(a, b))
            return false;
        int x0 = b.x - (a.x - b.w);
        int y0 = b.y - (a.y - b.h);
        int x1 = (a.x + a.w) - b.x;
        int y1 = (a.y + a.h) - b.y;
        if (x1 < x0)
            x0 = -x1;
        if (y1 < y0)
            y0 = -y1;

        if (Math.abs(x0) < Math.abs(y0))
            a.x += x0;
        else if (Math.abs(x0) > Math.abs(y0))
            a.y += y0;
        else {
            a.x += x0;
            a.y += y0;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

//для примера
final class Form extends JFrame {
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private BufferedImage dimg = null;
    private Graphics hdc = null;
    private Square[] arr = null;
    private Square square = null;

    Form() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Пример работы пересечений");
        setSize(640, 480);
        Dimension ssize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((ssize.width - getWidth()) / 2,
                (ssize.height - getHeight()) / 2);

        dimg = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        hdc = dimg.getGraphics();

        square = new Square();
        square.w = 50;
        square.h = 100;
        square.x = (getWidth() - square.w) / 2;
        square.y = getHeight() - square.h * 2;

        arr = new Square[3];
        arr[0] = new Square(90, 250, 100, 30);
        arr[1] = new Square(430, 150, 90, 100);
        arr[2] = new Square(250, 120, 50, 30);

        ActionListener tevent = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Form.this.repaint();
            }
        };
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10, tevent);
        timer.start();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                Form.this.on_keyPress(e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics dc) {
        hdc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        hdc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        hdc.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        hdc.fillRect(square.x, square.y, square.w, square.h);

        hdc.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Square q : arr) {
            hdc.fillRect(q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h);
        }
        dc.drawImage(dimg, 0, 0, null);
    }

    //управление пользователем синим квадратом
    void on_keyPress(KeyEvent e) {
        int vel = 3;
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                square.x -= vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                square.x += vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                square.y -= vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                square.y += vel;
                break;
        }

        //коллизия с пнями
        for (Square s : arr) {
            Square.isLockIntersect(square, s);
        }
    }
}


class BattleSquare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

И мой код игры

```
package things;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    static int vert = sSize.height;
    static int hor = sSize.width;
    private boolean running;
    public static int WIDTH = vert;
    public static int HEIGHT = hor;
    public static String NAME = "GAME OF YEAR";
    private static float xx = 0f;
    private static float yy = 0f;
    private boolean leftPressed = false;
    private boolean rightPressed = false;
    private boolean upPressed = false;
    private boolean downPressed = false;
    private boolean sprint = false;
    float speed = 0f;
    Image img = (new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("bcg.png"))).getImage();
    Image tree = (new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("tree.png"))).getImage();
    public static Sprite heroUP;
    public static Sprite heroDown;
    public static Sprite sprt;
    public static Sprite heroRight;
    public static Sprite heroleft;
    private static int x1;
    private static int y1;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gg.gif"));

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long delta;

        init();

        while (running) {

            delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            render();
            update(delta);
        }
    }


    public int x, y, w, h;

    Game() {
    }

    Game(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
    }

    public void init() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyInputHandler());
        heroUP = getSprite("things/man-up.png");
        heroDown = getSprite("things/man-down.png");
        heroleft = getSprite("things/man-left.png");
        heroRight = getSprite("things/man-right.png");
        sprt = getSprite("things/gg.png");


    }
    public static boolean isIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        return ((a.x < (b.x + b.w)) &&
                (b.x < (a.x + a.w)) &&
                (a.y < (b.y + b.h)) &&
                (b.y < (a.y + a.h)));
    }

    //пересечение квадратов с выталкиванием
    public static boolean isLockIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        if (!isIntersect(a, b))
            return false;
        int x0 = b.x - (a.x - b.w);
        int y0 = b.y - (a.y - b.h);
        int x1 = (a.x + a.w) - b.x;
        int y1 = (a.y + a.h) - b.y;
        if (x1 < x0)
            x0 = -x1;
        if (y1 < y0)
            y0 = -y1;

        if (Math.abs(x0) < Math.abs(y0))
            a.x += x0;
        else if (Math.abs(x0) > Math.abs(y0))
            a.y += y0;
        else {
            a.x += x0;
            a.y += y0;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public void painter(Graphics g)
    {
        x1 =  (int) xx;
        y1 = (int)yy;

        g.drawImage(img, x1, y1,null);

    }

    public void tree(Graphics g)
    {
        square = new Square();
        square.w = 50;
        square.h = 100;
        square.x    = (getWidth() - square.w) / 2;
        square.y    = getHeight() - square.h * 2;
        arr    = new Square[1];
        arr[0] = new Square(90, 250, 100,30);
        float h = tree.getHeight(null);
        float w = tree.getWidth(null);
        h = h/2;
        w = w/2;
        int widtht = 10;
        int heightt = 20;
        int posx=40;
        int posy=70;
        g.drawImage(tree, x1+posx*10-(int)w, y1+posy*10-(int)h,null);
    }
    private Graphics      hdc    = null;
    private Square[]      arr    = null;
    private Square        square = null;
    public void render() {

        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics(); //ïîëó÷àåì Graphics èç ñîçäàííîé íàìè BufferStrategy
        g.setColor(Color.black); //âûáðàòü öâåò
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); //çàïîëíèòü ïðÿìîóãîëüíèê
        painter(g);



        if(downPressed==true){
            heroDown.draw(g, hor/2-80, vert/2-60);
        }
        else if(rightPressed==true) {
            heroRight.draw(g, hor/2-80, vert/2-60);
        }
        else if(leftPressed==true) {
            heroleft.draw(g, hor/2-80, vert/2-60);
        }
        else if(upPressed==true) {
            heroUP.draw(g, hor/2-80, vert/2-60);
        }
        else {
            heroDown.draw(g, hor/2-80, vert/2-60);
        }
        tree(g);
        sprt.map(g,0,0);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show(); //ïîêàçàò
    }

    public void update(long delta) {

        if(sprint==true){
            speed=0.3f;
        }
        else {
            speed=0;
        }

        if (leftPressed == true) {
            xx = xx + 0.5f;
            xx = xx +speed;
        }
        if (rightPressed == true) {
            xx-=0.5f;
            xx=xx-speed;
        }
        if (upPressed == true) {
            yy= yy +0.5f;
            yy=yy+speed;
        }
        if (downPressed == true) {
            yy= yy - 0.5f;
            yy=yy-speed;
        }
    }

    public Sprite getSprite(String path) {
        BufferedImage sourceImage = null;

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
            sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(sourceImage.getSource()));

        return sprite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(hor, vert));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Game.NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        game.start();

    }

    private class KeyInputHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                leftPressed = true;
                System.out.println("left");
                System.out.println(xx);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                rightPressed = true;
                System.out.println("right");
                System.out.println(xx);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                upPressed = true;
                System.out.println("up");
                System.out.println(yy);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                downPressed = true;
                System.out.println("down");
                System.out.println(yy);
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                sprint = true;

            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                upPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                sprint = false;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Sprite.java-

```
    package things;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Sprite {
    private Image image;

    public Sprite(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return image.getWidth(null);
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return image.getHeight(null);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g,int x,int y) {
        g.drawImage(image,x,y,300,300,null);
    }
    public void map(Graphics а,int x,int y) {
        а.drawImage(image,x,y,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
    }
}
```

Не получается сделать как в примере
Нужно чтобы у объектов был невиидимый четырёх-угольник и чтобы нельзя было проходить сквозь дерево.

Comment: Можете привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) для вопроизведения проблемы, а не весь код вашей игры?

Comment: Изменил и добавил Sprite.java

Comment: сомневаюсь, что кто то займется разборкой вашего кода. опишите проблему, какого типа столкновения вы пытаетесь реализовать, что идет не так как хотелось бы? думаю, это повысит шансы на то что вам кто то поможет

Comment: Я привел работающий код,в котором реализовано то о чём я говорил.